# Python maintaining list of values

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, linked-list

I am trying to make colour maps using 3 specific lists(peak, X3 and Y3). The code of the lists that I have written where built using the insert function. The code looks like follow:

```
for k in range(112):

   if (act_info.nb_act[k]) >0:
       max_V.insert(k,np.max(array_data[:,k]))#find the maximum voltage for the set of samples of each channel
       min_V.insert(k,np.min(array_data[:,k]))                     #find the minimum voltage for the set of samples of each channe
       dif = ((((max_V[k] - min_V[k])/(4096.0))*10.0)/elec_array.chan[k].gain)*1000
       peak.insert(k,dif)  #then compute the difference between the max and min to find the peak-to-peak value
       X3.insert(k, elec_array.chan[k].x)                          #get the coordinates
       Y3.insert(k, elec_array.chan[k].y)

    else:

        Z2as[k] = k
        aa=aa+1
```

My intention is to get all 3 lists and record when act_info.b_act[k] is not bigger than zero.
When I try to run this code this error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/AhmedNiri/Ahmed/2D_Mapping_Program_V8.py", line 433, in on_scar_button
    self.scar_map(file_info, elec_array, aux_elec, act_info, act, act_type, array_data)
  File "/Users/AhmedNiri/Ahmed/2D_Mapping_Program_V8.py", line 911, in scar_map
    dif = ((((max_V[k] - min_V[k])/(4096.0))*10.0)/elec_array.chan[k].gain)*1000
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It seems like when act_info.b_act[k] is smaller than 0 it goes into the else statement records that its smaller than zero and then seem to have interrupted the list generation and hence gives me this error. I haven't been working with python for too long to know how to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance for your help :).

Answer (score 2):

Your stack trace tells you exactly what you just said. The index, *k*, is going out of range. It is trying to call something in the data (list, dictionary or tuple, etc) that does not exist. to avoid this crashing your program, wrap your if conditional with a `try: except:` block.

```
for k in range(112):

  try:

     if (act_info.nb_act[k]) >0:
         max_V.insert(k,np.max(array_data[:,k]))#find the maximum voltage for the set of samples of each channel
         min_V.insert(k,np.min(array_data[:,k]))                     #find the minimum voltage for the set of samples of each channe
         dif = ((((max_V[k] - min_V[k])/(4096.0))*10.0)/elec_array.chan[k].gain)*1000
         peak.insert(k,dif)  #then compute the difference between the max and min to find the peak-to-peak value
         X3.insert(k, elec_array.chan[k].x)                          #get the coordinates
         Y3.insert(k, elec_array.chan[k].y)

    except IndexError:
      pass
```

it is set to pass, so if that case happens again, it won't crash your program. You can set it to close the program, or flag the user and then ignore it, etc.

Comment: But how do you continue the sequence after it has been broken. Because if I understand correctly, this code will pass the exception but how about the numbers after the exception? Because they seem to be not used and I'dd like to use them. Could you please elaborate, I appreciate your help. @awbemauler

Comment: are you talking about the code in your else statement?

Comment: no I'm talking about after the else, the values seem to not be generated. This would mean i guess that the list stops at the exception and does not generate the rest of the list. The reason I'dd like to have the rest of the list is to generate a map. @awbemauler